# What constituents in soft drinks are the cause their strong pungent smell?

Tags: physical-chemistry, food-chemistry

Wikipedia and PubChem tells us that $\ce{CO2}$ is odorless in lower concentrations but can have a mildly pungent acidic smell at higher concentrations.

However, there is no pungent smell from chemical reactions such as the combustion of cooking gas, effervescence from carbonate upon the addition of an acid, and the sublimation of a piece of dry ice.

But many soft drinks and soda waters (including Sprite, 7 up, Pepsi, Coca-Cola, and Thums Up) emit, open opening, a strong burning smell that may cause severe irritation to eye and nose. The same burning is experienced during the [burping (or belching)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burping) that comes out after consuming a glass of such drink

So, I want to know, is this due to $\ce{CO2}$? Maybe the manufacturers pump too much $\ce{CO2}$ into their drinks that it reacts in a different way than $\ce{CO2}$ from LPG-oven flames or carbonate/acid reactions? Or maybe that 'burning effect' is due to some mysterious additive?

Comment: Yes, it is $\ce{CO2}$ and not some additive. It is just that we can't feel it in low concentrations, exactly as Wikipedia says.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33376929#33376929 there is phosphoric acid. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33377067#33377067  links [here](http://www.fooducate.com/app#!page=post&id=57A324B5-180F-C75A-4AC5-92AAAF82E9E5)

Comment: Yes there is; so what? It is not like you pour Coca-cola down into your nose to smell the solution. Phosphoric acid _per se_ is not very volatile. Sure, some of it might get to your nose in the form of tiny droplets, but those are responsible for a minor component of the smell at best. I can attest to that. I did smell pure $\ce{CO2}$ out of curiosity.

Comment: and that pure CO2 was just same as cold-drinks? or more? or less (approx)?

Comment: Yes, pretty much so.

Comment: @IvanNeretin you could write an answer.

Comment: CO2 doesn't irritate. I believe burning is caused by acidic droplets. You can prove/disprove this by arranging experiment with some membrane to retain the droplets.

Comment: @sa7 Have you ever tried breathing nearly pure CO2?

Comment: Nope, I think I would loose consciousness very soon.

Comment: It is definitely $\ce{CO2}$, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that strong smell is mostly $\ce{CO2}$, possibly with a faint tint of volatile aromatizers from the beverage.

Our sense of smell works in surprisingly non-straightforward ways. Indeed, the smells of the same compound in high and low concentrations are sometimes perceived as quite different, to the point of being totally unrecognizable. A classic example is [skatole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skatole), which may produce either a pleasant flowery aroma or a fecal stench, depending on the concentration alone. Looks like $\ce{CO2}$ is just a somewhat less extreme example of the same effect.

Air with 5% of $\ce{CO2}$ doesn't smell much of anything (not that it is OK to breathe it for long), which leads most people to conclude that $\ce{CO2}$ is odorless. This is quite wrong. If you try to inhale some *pure* $\ce{CO2}$ (**which I do not recommend or endorse**), that's when the smell kicks in. Your breathing just stops instinctively, as if you were trying to inhale water. By that moment, though, some $\ce{CO2}$ reaches your olfactory nerves. I am at a loss of words as to what it feels like. Being slapped across your face with a shovel seems like a moderately adequate approximation. Besides, you feel that familiar refreshing sharp odor of an open Coca-cola bottle.

So no, this is not due to some mysterious additive.

Comment: +1'd for "Our sense of smell works in surprisingly non-straightforward ways".  It is surprising fact that scatole, which is one of the bad-smelling component of stool; produce a pleasant aroma when the concentration is low!. Same has been told about [indole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indole#General_properties_and_occurrence), too!. However It is tough to accept because fecal-odor smells bad even-when it comes from distance. And after purging; when the bathroom-is cleaned, the remaining trace of smell is never felt pleasant.