# Can you convert smells to variables?

Tags: chromatography, smell

Is there a way to map smells to numerical values of different variables?

I.e. With RGB colours, each colour is made up of numerical values from 0-255. For example, red is (255,0,0), and yellow is (255,255,0). Is there a way to do this with smells. I.e, the smell of Candy is (140,70,255), and the smell of grass is (255,34,27)? How many different sets of numbers (like red, green and blue) would you need, and what would they represent?

Comment: Not really a chemistry question, your question would be more appropriate for Biology.SE.  That said, there are around 400 types of receptors for the sense of smell in humans so I'd say plausible depending on the degree of perfection you desire.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Biology.SE

Comment: I'm not familiar with Biology.SE, but if they are like us, they too will close this question as offtopic. As to the point of the question, I never heard of such a map for smells, nor do I have any idea on approaching this problem. Then again, the idea of a map for colors is also far from obvious, yet here is RGB. Maybe the problem with smells is inherently more difficult.

Comment: Smelling is not a 3D problem, but more like 400D. That's the approximate number of different receptors in the human nose.

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorry for posting to the wrong place/having such a strange question. Wasn't really sure where to place it. So far, no responses on the Biology SE. Do you think that there would be a way to graph the 400D/know where I could find any data on this?

Comment: There are three primary colors, so you can use three numbers to describe a color (the RGB and CMYK models do not use primary colors, but that is just for convenience). There are five primary tastes, so you could represent any taste with five numbers. There is not any consensus about the number of primary smells, the lowest numbers being seven or ten, depending on the source, but they seem to be very limited. Once the primary smells are fixed, you could use a vector to describe each smell, but it surely will be a huge one.

Comment: Also, the response works in essentially different ("non-linear") ways. Light blue and dark blue colors look _related_ to us. Not so with smells. See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62342/what-constituents-in-soft-drinks-are-the-cause-their-strong-pungent-smell/62439#62439

Comment: A very interesting read. Thanks Ivan. And thanks Raoul for explaining so clearly.

Comment: It does not work that way, or, we don't yet know, how it works. But an interesting term/keyword is often used, **[olfactory coding](https://www.google.com/search?q=olfactory+coding)**.